# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: laravel, gulp, webpack, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

I working on a Laravel 5.3 project. I am getting below errors when I am running `gulp` command in CMD.

[image]

Could anyone say how can I get a error less result ?

**gulpfile.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});


elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.webpack('app.js');
}); 


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "buble": "^0.14.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-browserify-official": "^0.1.3",
    "laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-lte": "^2.3.7",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you run `npm install` or `yarn`, to install dependencies?

Comment: We cannot help, because we're seeing error messages like you and it's saying the problem is either in the elixir declaration in `gulpfile.js`, or in the `package.json` declarations. Please share your code.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam vai, I added those files.

Comment: And you ran `npm install` first and then `gulp`, right?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, I used `npm install`, but could not get any solution.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam vai, yes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your using Laravel 5.5 or above, simply add:

```
mix.webpackConfig({ node: { fs: 'empty' }})
```

to your `webpack.mix.js` file.

Comment: Please note in webpack > 5, you now have to use 
```mix.webpackConfig({ resolve: { fallback: { fs: false } }```

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere Thanks so much! Been trying to fix this for so long!

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere thanks, this is what I needed for laravel 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  }
});
```

To your **gulpfile.js**.  Looks like this is a known webpack problem. Here's your file edited:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  }
});


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});


elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.webpack('app.js');
}); 


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I use that ?

Comment: As I said in the anwser, add to your gulpfile.js. Edited to show how

Comment: @Thanks for your reply. I am getting new error now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZhL6.png

Comment: Looks like it's not finding webpack, but that command is working where, Laravel 5.3 too, so try elixir in small caps