# Webpack - NodeJS - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am getting following error, when build nodejs project with webpack.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Sample\node-ts-sample\node_modules\mime'
 @ ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts
 @ ./src/index.ts
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950176/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs)

Answer (score 26):

It was a node application. Added a following node in webpack config solved my issue

```
 target:'node',
```

I refereed the article at  https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, I love it when that happens :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this to your webpack config file:

```
const webpackConfig = {
  target: 'node'
};
module.exports = webpackConfig;
```