# How to resolve the "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'" in nuxt.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm a bit new to node, but from a lot of searching, it looks like 'fs' broke a lot of things in the past. I've come across several packages I've tried to install via npm and have run into the `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'` error way too much.

I've run the npm install, and fs downloads a [placeholder package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs), but I'm really at a halt because a package (among several) still has a dependency on fs.

Nearly [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950176/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs) [solution](https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/elixir/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs?page=1) I [find](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447) has resulted in declaring `fs` as empty in the node section of the webpack settings:

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
},
```

Unfortunately, I'm using Vue.js and nuxt and there is no webpack settings file (that I know of). I've tried to add it into my nuxt_config.js but haven't been successful.
    extend(config, ctx) {
     config.node = {
       fs: "empty"
     };
    }

**Is there a way to run the exclude inside of the nuxt_config? Also, is there a way to run it while still preserving my settings to run eslint on save?**

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  // Run ESLint on save
  if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    })
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion is correct, according to the webpack see the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#other-node-core-libraries) you should set the `fs` module to `'empty'`.

Have you tried inserting it into your nuxt configuration on the top level config within build block?

```
build: {
  extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {

     config.node: {
        fs: 'empty'
      }

     // ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, @adamrights. I thought I'd done it the way you presented, but obviously, I did not -  it works correctly the way you've presented. Can I ask a followup: is there a way to combine what you have  with my eslint-on-save settings `if (ctx.isDev...` above inside of the extend block?

Comment: `{ isDev, isClient }` is the ctx object in your example.

try...
    build: {
        ...
        // EXTEND
        extend (config, { isClient }) {
          if (isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            },{
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            })
         }
       }
     },

Comment: Thanks - I was able to get it ... realized I was just using a comma to separate the two sections and I need to remove it. Very much appreciation for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it helps. In my case this error appeared all of a sudden and wasn't able to tell why. After trying everything (deleting and reinstalling npm packages, etc...) I found out that VS CODE auto referenced a package in a file I had just saved and I didn't notice.

In my case it added
`import { query } from 'express'.`

Deleted the line and everything worked again.

Comment: You just saved my day.... or week. The exact same thing happened to me and I've been reinstalling and deleting things like crazy. Thank you so much Nadine!

Comment: Thankyou so much, this was my issue also. Was sending me crazy.

Comment: I've spent a whole  day in frustration and the answer was this simple!! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The usage may change according to versions.

In my case, i've to define confing.node with "=" character.

```
    build: {
        extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) { 
            config.node = {
                fs: "empty"
            }
        })
    }
```